# Apache SkyWalking, Zipkin Receiver is not activated

Tags: skywalking

By following the documentation steps, I wasn't able to activate Zipkin Receiver in apache-skywalking-apm-bin-es7-8.7.0

my application.yml is

```
cluster:
  selector: ${SW_CLUSTER:standalone}

...

storage:
  selector: ${SW_STORAGE:zipkin-elasticsearch7}

...

  zipkin-elasticsearch7:
    nameSpace: ${SW_NAMESPACE:""}
    clusterNodes: ${SW_STORAGE_ES_CLUSTER_NODES:localhost:9200}
    protocol: ${SW_STORAGE_ES_HTTP_PROTOCOL:"http"}
    trustStorePath: ${SW_STORAGE_ES_SSL_JKS_PATH:""}
    trustStorePass: ${SW_STORAGE_ES_SSL_JKS_PASS:""}
    dayStep: ${SW_STORAGE_DAY_STEP:1}
    indexShardsNumber: ${SW_STORAGE_ES_INDEX_SHARDS_NUMBER:1}
    indexReplicasNumber: ${SW_STORAGE_ES_INDEX_REPLICAS_NUMBER:1}
    superDatasetDayStep: ${SW_SUPERDATASET_STORAGE_DAY_STEP:-1}
    superDatasetIndexShardsFactor: ${SW_STORAGE_ES_SUPER_DATASET_INDEX_SHARDS_FACTOR:5}
    superDatasetIndexReplicasNumber: ${SW_STORAGE_ES_SUPER_DATASET_INDEX_REPLICAS_NUMBER:0}
    user: ${SW_ES_USER:""}
    password: ${SW_ES_PASSWORD:""}
    secretsManagementFile: ${SW_ES_SECRETS_MANAGEMENT_FILE:""}
    bulkActions: ${SW_STORAGE_ES_BULK_ACTIONS:5000}
    flushInterval: ${SW_STORAGE_ES_FLUSH_INTERVAL:15}
    concurrentRequests: ${SW_STORAGE_ES_CONCURRENT_REQUESTS:2}
    resultWindowMaxSize: ${SW_STORAGE_ES_QUERY_MAX_WINDOW_SIZE:10000}
    metadataQueryMaxSize: ${SW_STORAGE_ES_QUERY_MAX_SIZE:5000}
    segmentQueryMaxSize: ${SW_STORAGE_ES_QUERY_SEGMENT_SIZE:200}
    profileTaskQueryMaxSize: ${SW_STORAGE_ES_QUERY_PROFILE_TASK_SIZE:200}
    oapAnalyzer: ${SW_STORAGE_ES_OAP_ANALYZER:"{\"analyzer\":{\"oap_analyzer\":{\"type\":\"stop\"}}}"}
    oapLogAnalyzer: ${SW_STORAGE_ES_OAP_LOG_ANALYZER:"{\"analyzer\":{\"oap_log_analyzer\":{\"type\":\"standard\"}}}"}
    advanced: ${SW_STORAGE_ES_ADVANCED:""}

...

receiver_zipkin:
  selector: ${SW_RECEIVER_ZIPKIN:-}
  default:
    host: ${SW_RECEIVER_ZIPKIN_HOST:0.0.0.0}
    port: ${SW_RECEIVER_ZIPKIN_PORT:9411}
    contextPath: ${SW_RECEIVER_ZIPKIN_CONTEXT_PATH:/}
    jettyMinThreads: ${SW_RECEIVER_ZIPKIN_JETTY_MIN_THREADS:1}
    jettyMaxThreads: ${SW_RECEIVER_ZIPKIN_JETTY_MAX_THREADS:200}
    jettyIdleTimeOut: ${SW_RECEIVER_ZIPKIN_JETTY_IDLE_TIMEOUT:30000}
    jettyAcceptorPriorityDelta: ${SW_RECEIVER_ZIPKIN_JETTY_DELTA:0}
    jettyAcceptQueueSize: ${SW_RECEIVER_ZIPKIN_QUEUE_SIZE:0}
    instanceNameRule: ${SW_RECEIVER_ZIPKIN_INSTANCE_NAME_RULE:[spring.instance_id,node_id]}
```

Started with

```
./bin/startup.sh
```

ports 11800 12900 are listed as listening
ui is working
port 9411 is not listed as listening

Answer (score 0):

You should set `SW_RECEIVER_ZIPKIN= default` through the system environment, or change the `application.yml` about `selector: ${SW_RECEIVER_ZIPKIN:default}`

You should follow the **Level 2** instruction in the backend set up doc, https://skywalking.apache.org/docs/main/v8.7.0/en/setup/backend/backend-setup/#applicationyml